# Mute the audio at a particular interval of time while casting the video in ios using chromecast

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, chromecast, google-cast

I am working on chrome cast based application using google cast api. Initially, I am joining to the chromecast session from youtube and playing the video. Later I joined to this session from my application.

There is a requirement in my application to mute the audio at particular interval of time.

I required to mute the audio from 00:01:34:03(hh:mm:ss:ms) to 00:01:34:15((hh:mm:ss:ms).

Converting the time to seconds in the below way.
Time to seconds conversion: (00*60*60)+(01*60)+34+(03/1000) = 94.003 -> Mute start time

Calling the mute method after the interval of: Mute start time - Current streaming position

I am using  approximateStreamPosition value (in GCKMediaControlChannel header file) to known the stream position of the casting video. It is returning the value in double format say 94.70801001358.

In this 94 is seconds duration, what does the value after the decimal point indicates(.70801001358). Is it milliseconds?  If so can I round it to three digits.

As I required to mute the audio in milliseconds duration, is it causes any delay or advance muting of the audio if I round off the value.

Answer (score 0):

The 0.70801001358 is in seconds; I am not sure what you mean by asking if that is in milliseconds. In milliseconds, that number would be 708.01001358.

You wont be able to have millisecond accuracy in controlling mute (or any other control command for that matter); just setting up a command and transfer time from your iOS device to Chromecast together will throw your calculations off by a good number of milliseconds.